# What's the best way to write the following?

Tags: punctuation

But on this morning, I sat alone with my thoughts. No radio. No calls. Just me.

Should other punctuation be used to make it more proper?

Comment: "More proper" and "best way"  is a matter of opinion. Punctuation depends on the style guide you subscribe to.//and this sounds like creative writing, which often ignores the "rules".

Comment: There are other ways it might be punctuated, but the way you have it is perfectly OK.  (The first nit I'd pick is the comma.)